# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..99, inclusive: 100

Tags: flutter

I am new in a flutter. so maybe this is a silly question I am asking.

I am creating an example of list view using random list tile but when I scroll after value Item 99 I am getting below error.

[image]

hear is my code sample.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> getListElement() {
  var items = List<String>.generate(100, (counter) => "Item $counter");
  return items;
}

Widget getListView(context) {
  var listItems = getListElement();


  var listView = ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(listItems[index]),
    );
  });

  return listView;
}

class RandomListViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Listing View Demo'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: getListView(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView builder has itemCount paramter to generate items according to some length.You are having 100 items so you need to specify itemCount to 100.I've added **itemCount: listItems.length** to generate list according to the length of listItems list(i.e 100).

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> getListElement() {
  var items = List<String>.generate(100, (counter) => "Item $counter");
  return items;
}

Widget getListView(context) {
  var listItems = getListElement();


  var listView = ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(listItems[index]),
    );
  },itemCount: listItems.length,);

  return listView;
}

class RandomListViewExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Listing View Demo'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: getListView(context),
    );
  }
}
```